# For which values a, b does this integral converge

Tags: calculus, integration

Determine all $a$ and $b$ for which the this converges:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(\sin^ax^2)(\cos^bx)}$$

I'm not sure how to approach the problem.
I've tried using the comparison test, setting:

$$f(x)=1/(sin^ax^2)(cos^bx)$$
$$g(x)=1/(sin^ax^2)$$
then doing
$$\lim_{x \to 0}f(x)/g(x)dx = 1/(cos^bx) = 1$$

then by comparison test I should get that whenever g(x) converges, so does f(x) -> but I'm not sure where to continue from here

Ideally I would like to show that g(x) converges whenever a = ??? and then I can also solve for b

Some help or a general direction would be appreciated
note that I saw this question: [For which values of $p$ and $q$ does an improper integral converge](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309812/for-which-values-of-p-and-q-does-an-improper-integral-converge)
However this one is different, and I did not understand how to apply the answers given there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(a, b)
=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(\sin^ax^2)(\cos^bx)}
$.

Around $x=0$,
$\dfrac1{\sin^ax^2}
\approx \dfrac1{x^{2a}}
=x^{-2a}
$
and
$\dfrac1{\cos^bx}
\approx 1
$,
so the integral is like
$\lim_{r \to 0}\int_r^c x^{-2a}dx
=\lim_{r \to 0}\dfrac{x^{-2a+1}}{-2a+1}|_r^c
$
and this diverges for
$-2a+1 < 0$
or
$a > \frac12$.

Similarly,
around $x = \pi/2$,
$\cos(\pi/2-x)
=\sin(x)
\approx x$
so
so the integral is like
$\lim_{r \to 0}\int_r^c x^{-b}dx
=\lim_{r \to 0}\dfrac{x^{-b+1}}{-b+1}|_r^c
$
and this diverges for
$b > 1$.

You can show that
the integral converges for
$a < \frac12$ and
$b < 1$.

For $a=\frac12$
and
$b = 1$
the integral behaves like
$\lim_{r \to 0}\int_r^c \dfrac{dt}{t}
=\lim_{r \to 0}\ln(t)|_r^c
$
and this diverges.